# Python Pandas select rows between two row numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I am bringing in an excel sheet into a dataframe like below.  I want to get all rows from Start and End.

```py
start_row=df[df['Column1']=="Start"].index.values
end_row=df[df['Column1']=="End"].index.values
```

Is there a way to do something like `df.iloc[[start_row[0]:end_row[0]]]`, I can do
`df.iloc[[start_row[0],end_row[0]]]` but this only returns the Start Row and End Row and I need all in between.

Thank you!

```
Column1 Column2
Start    15
0        12
1         7
2         4
3         9
3        11
End      12 
1        18
2        24
etc      56
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```py
out = df.iloc[start_row[0]:end_row[0], :]
```

```
print(out)

  Column1  Column2
0   Start       15
1       0       12
2       1        7
3       2        4
4       3        9
5       3       11
```

Depending if want to include `Start`, you can optionally add `1` to `start_row[0]` like

```py
out = df.iloc[start_row[0]+1:end_row[0], :]
```

Comment: Works, thank you

Comment: @MarkProuty **If your question is solved**, say thank you by ***accepting** the solution that is **best for your needs***. The **accept check** is below the up/down arrow at the top left of the answer. A new solution can be accepted if a better one shows up. If you have a reputation of 15 or greater, you may also vote on the quality of an answer, with the up or down arrow. **Leave a comment if a solution doesn't answer the question**. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?. Thank you.